# Как получить индекс элемента со стилем?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В соседнем топике возник вопрос, решил его, но хочется узнать более оптимальный способ. Есть хтмл, внутри прописаны стили, **задача** - найти индекс элемента с определенным стилем. Решил задачу ниже двумя способами, но хотел бы узнать, можно ли решить задачу более оптимально?

Можно ли тут применить методы `each(), map()`? Предложите ваш способ определения индекса элемента.

```js
$(function(){
    var res = $('#res');
    var res2 = $('#res2');
    var i = $('li').filter(function(index) {
        if ($(this).css('font-size') == '17px') {
            return index;
        }
    }).index();
    res.text(i);
    res2.text($('li[style*=17px]').index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
index решение первое: <span id="res">res</span><br>
index решение второе: <span id="res2">res</span><br>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li style="font-size: 14px">14px</li>
        <li style="font-size: 15px">15px</li>
        <li style="font-size: 16px">16px</li>
        <li style="font-size: 17px">17px</li>
        <li style="font-size: 18px">18px</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. Способ с `each` лучше, т. к. он перебирает только нужные элементы, т. е. при нахождении останавливает перебор.

Предполагается, что поиск делается по некоторому уникальному селектору, т. е. результаты из разных списков не попадают в набор.

```js
$("#res").text($("li").map(function (i) {
  return $(this).css('font-size') !== '17px' ? null : i;
})[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

index: <output id="res">res</output>

<ul>
  <li style="font-size: 14px">14px</li>
  <li style="font-size: 15px">15px</li>
  <li style="font-size: 16px">16px</li>
  <li style="font-size: 17px">17px</li>
  <li style="font-size: 18px">18px</li>
</ul>
```

```js
$("li").each(function (i) {
  if ($(this).css('font-size') === '17px') {
    $("#res").text(i);
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

index: <output id="res">res</output>

<ul>
  <li style="font-size: 14px">14px</li>
  <li style="font-size: 15px">15px</li>
  <li style="font-size: 16px">16px</li>
  <li style="font-size: 17px">17px</li>
  <li style="font-size: 18px">18px</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: да, спасибо, очень простенько оказалось.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, а принять ответ?

Comment: @qwerty может еще кто-то добавит)